# Flask WTF error - CSRF session token is missing (but actually not)

Tags: python, session, flask, token, csrf

Currently trying to fix this issue, I have browsed many posts but still cannot solve this problem hence this message to the community :)

I am creating a dev/test environment for a Flask based website and I have to duplicate the current website into a subdomain, such as from `mydomain.com` to `dev.mydomain.com` and so on for the additional related services such as elastic search (e.g. from `es.mydomain.com` to `es-dev.mydomain.com`).

So here I am, I deployed everything through Nginx, the main website `dev.mydomain.com` and all services run and are accessible. BUT I cannot log in to Flask which throws me an error `400 missing CSRF session token` when there is actually 2 session tokens ... it seems that 1 duplicate is created in the form submission process as the cookie holds 2 `session` keys.

Before form submission

- Original cookie keys: `_ga=...`; `_gid=...`; `session=...`
- Dev cookie keys: `session=...`; `Domain=.dev.mydomain.com`; `Secure`; `HttpOnly`; `Path=/`

After form submission

- Original website cookie keys: `_ga=...`; `_gid=...`; `session=...`
- Dev wbesite cookie keys: `_ga=...`; `_gid=...`; `session=...`; `session=...`

CSRF is enabled for the whole app via `csrf.init_app(app)` and my Flask config is:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
REMEMBER_COOKIE_SECURE = True
REMEMBER_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

I'm trying different config flavors but no improvement so far ...

Some help would be appreciated as always, thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

For the record, one just needs to set the `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` configuration paramater to solve that problem

Cf. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#SESSION_COOKIE_NAME